# How much of tax-paid money can I keep in the US, as an Indian citizen?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, capital-gains-tax, dtaa

I work for a company in India which is listed in the Nasdaq. Recently, I sold some RSUs, the proceeds (after tax deduction at the time of sale) of which is lying with the bank account associated with my trading account in the US.

Can I continue to keep the money in the US and invest there?
Is there a limit to how much money I can keep/invest in the US. And for any incidence of tax on capital gains on my investment in the US, where should I pay / file my tax?

Answer (score 1):

The US will let you keep as much money as you want to within its borders regardless of your citizenship. You'll owe capital gains tax in the US unless you're subject to a tax treaty (which you would probably make as an election in the year of the transaction). I don't know if India has any rules about how it governs its citizens' foreign assets, but the US requires citizens to file a form annually declaring foreign accounts over $10,000. You may be subject to additional Indian taxes if India taxes global income like the US does.

Comment: Nearly every country taxes the global income *of its residents*.  What the US does which is fairly unusual is to tax the global income of its citizens, and persons having resident status, even when they are tax-resident elsewhere.